# Merge two objects by matching key while following Flow rules

Tags: javascript

I have created a function as shown below, which should append the array value into the first object.

Let's say we have given data below:

```
subjects = {
  student1: ['Math', 'Science'],
  student2: ['Math', 'Physics', 'English'],
};

students = {
 student1: {
    // other data
    subjectsList: [],
 },
 student2: {
    // other data
    subjectsList: [],
 },
};
```

Function code below:

```
const merge = (subjects: Object, students: Object) => {
    Object.keys(subjects).forEach((id: Object) => {
      const subjectsList = subjects[id];
      const student = students[id];

      if (student) {
        const updatedStudent = {
          ...student,
          subjectsList,
        };

        students[id] = updatedStudent;
      }
    });

    return students;
  };
```

This would result in a flow error:

```
Cannot access the computed property using object type [1].

app/reducers/subjects.reducer.js:42:32
42|           const student = students[id];
                                   ^^

References:
app/reducers/subjects.reducer.js:40:48
40|         Object.keys(subjects).forEach((id: Object) => {
            ^^^^^^ [1]
```

Comment: i haven't seen anyone use the syntax 'subjects: Object' in function param before, what does it do?

Comment: @ChrisLi I'm using `flow` just to check the types, it's kind of like typescript.

Comment: what is stand...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.keys(subjects).forEach((id: Object)`

The `id` in the `.forEach((id) =>` is not an *Object*, but a *String*

If you remove the typehinting (or whatever it is called).

```
const merge = (subjects, students) => {
    Object.keys(subjects).forEach((id) => {
      const subjectsList = subjects[id];
      const student = students[id];

      if (stand) {
        const updatedStudent = {
          ...student,
          subjectsList,
        };

        students[id] = updatedStudent;
      }
    });

    return students;
  };
```

I think this will work.